# Graph Processing - Vertex Centric Model vs Matrix-Vector Multiplication

Tags: graph

**Vertex-centric** and **matrix-vector multiplication** are two most famous models to process graph structured data, I am looking for a comparison between them, which one is better and in what terms.

Comparison can be in terms of performance, express-ability(number of algorithms that can be implemented), scalability and any other aspect I am missing to list here :)

I have been looking around but could not find a comparison between the two approaches.

Thanks in advance